# Linq Query Return Error with Union Operator

Tags: c#, angularjs, linq, wcf

I am consuming wcf service into angular js web application . I have two tables .I am joining two tables records into single record and displaying the records in angular js application. When I have record for both table ,its able to retrieve but if i have only one table record in database ,its do not display anything with this following Query ..

```
 public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
        {

            var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
            using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
            {
                var CombinedQuery = (from x in context.Current_Account_Deposit
                                     join y in context.Current_Account_Withdraw
                                     on x.Account_Number equals y.Account_Number
                                     where x.Account_Number == accountNumber //Modify it
                                     select new
                                     {
                                         x.Account_Number,
                                         x.Account_Holder_Name,
                                         x.Transcation_Type,
                                         x.Amount,
                                         Transcation_Type1 = y.Transcation_Type,
                                         Amount1 = y.Amount,

                                         // put other properties here 
                                     }).ToList();

                var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

                return js.Serialize(CombinedQuery); // return JSON string
            }

        }  
    }
}
```

Here is the database record.
[image]

Here is the screen shot when i run the application and enter account number 1 and its have records for both table and its able to display .
[image]

Here is the screen shot when i enter account number 15 which have only record for Current_Account_Withdraw table ,do not have record for Current_Account_Deposit  table and its do not display anything . [image]

Then i change it to this .

```
public string TranscationDetails(string Account_Number)
    {

        var accountNumber = int.Parse(Account_Number);//It could be better to use TryParse
        using (HalifaxDatabaseEntities context = new HalifaxDatabaseEntities())
        {
            var DepsoitQuery = (from x in context.Current_Account_Deposit
                                 join y in context.Current_Account_Withdraw
                                 on x.Account_Number equals y.Account_Number
                                 into JoinedList
                                 from y in JoinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 where x.Account_Number == accountNumber //Modify it
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     x.Account_Number,
                                     x.Account_Holder_Name,
                                     x.Amount,

                                     // put other properties here 
                                 }).ToList();

            var withdrawQuery = (from y in context.Current_Account_Deposit
                                 join x in context.Current_Account_Withdraw
                                 on y.Account_Number equals x.Account_Number
                                 into JoinedList
                                 from x in JoinedList.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                 where x.Account_Number == accountNumber
                                 select new
                                 {
                                     y.Amount,
                                 }).ToList();

            var CombinedQuery = DepsoitQuery.Union(withdrawQuery).ToList();//**error on this line**

            var js = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();

            return js.Serialize(CombinedQuery); // return JSON string
        }

    }
```

Here is the Error i got when i compile it .
    **'List<>' does not contain a definition for 'Union' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Union<>(IQueryable<>, IEnumerable<>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<>'**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DepositQuery` is a list generated from this anonymous type:

```
select new
{
    x.Account_Number,
    x.Account_Holder_Name,
    x.Amount,
}
```

Your `withdrawQuery` is a list generated from this anonymous type:

```
select new
{
    y.Amount,
}
```

These types are not compatible.  (You can't "union" a string and an integer for example, or two separate classes -- which is what you're doing when you have two disparate anonymous types)  You need to make both types declare the same properties of the same type if you want to be able to use them together.

For example, you could declare the second anonymous type as:

```
select new
{
    Account_Number = 0,
    Account_Holer_Name = "Unknown",
    y.Amount,
}
```

Your actual solution will depend on what values you actually want to default to.

Comment: Take look my first query where i do not get my expected result and then i tried this way